# #list index out of range

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

```
def isexact(pat):
    for c in pat.upper():
        if c not in 'ATGC':
            return 0
    return 1

def print_matches(ofh, enz, matches):
    if matches:
        print >>ofh, "Enzyme %s matches at:" % enz,
        for m in matches:
            print >>ofh, m,
        print >>ofh
    else:
        print >>ofh, "No match found for enzyme %s." % enz

def get_site_only(pat):
    newpat = ""
    for c in pat:
        if c.isalpha():
            newpat += c
    return newpat

def findpos(seq, pat):
    matches = []
    current_match = seq.find(pat)
    while current_match != -1:
        matches.append(current_match)
        current_match =seq.find(pat, current_match+1)
    return matches


seq = ""


ifh = open("C:\Python27\\link_cutzymes.txt",'r')
ofh = open("C:\Python27\\re-en-output.txt", "w")       

line = ifh.readline()

while line:
    fields = line.split()
    name = fields[0]
    pat = get_site_only(fields[2])

    if isexact(pat):
        print_matches(ofh, name, findpos(seq, pat))
        line = ifh.readline()
    else:
        line = ifh.readline()

ofh.close() 
ifh.close()
```

it is showing list index error can help me

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/ram/Desktop/rest_enz7.py", line 55, in 
>       name = fields[0] IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: The nice thing here is that you get an error on a line that doesn't show in the code. Or perhaps, wrongly copied.

Comment: please copy paste your actual code.

Answer (score 0):

`name = fields[0]` - you probably are reading an empty line, splitting it, and accessing it at index 0, which is out of range for an empty list..

you can make sure your file contains only lines of your format, check for empty lines in the code, or use `try` and `except` to name a few options.

Answer (score 0):

while reading the data from file,if data is not exist to split,it will not convert into list. I can see in your code  **name = fields[0]** is causing error.

At that time please use try and except in your code.

you can rewrite the code as :

```
try:
 fields = line.split()
 name = fields[0]
except:
 pass
```

Answer (score 0):

What a `string[x]` does is get the xth letter of the list. This means that if there is no object in the xth position then you get an error. 
So if `name = fields[0]` returns an error then `fields`must be an empty list (It would look like this: []) because there is no first object (Python counts from zero so letter 0 is letter 1, letter 1 is letter 2 and so on). You can fix this with a `try:` and `except:` like so:

```
try:
    name = fields[0]
except:
    name = '' #Or whatever code you want to run if it fails
```

In the place of `name = fields[0]`